# Django rest framework execute custom function without viewset (remote procedure call)

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I'm triying to do a remote procedure call  (regular call to server by ajax) from AJAX to a Django server with **Django Rest Framework (DRF)** for maintenance tasks.

### Problem

I only have model viewsets and only need to execute a basic server task, for example, delete all items in one model.

### Solution

Use generic apiview from DRF. See code on answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope it helps:

**views.py**

```
# File: my_app.views.py
from rest_framework.response import Response


# Basic DRF api view.
@api_view(['GET'])
# Default Json render, you can use a custom render like text plain, etc.
@renderer_classes([JSONRenderer])
# Authentication by session or basic http
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication))
# Basic permission: it requires to be authenticated.
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
# The function name will be the name you must use for remote call.
def delete_elements(request):
    # Delete all items from one model
    deleted_items = MyModel.objects.all().delete()
    json_response = {"ok": True}
    return Response(json_response)
```

**urls.py**

```
# File: my_app.urls.py
from django.urls import path

from my_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('delete_elements/', views.delete_elements),
]
```

Now you can use AJAX or CLI to call this function.

- [Apiview](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view).
- [JSON render](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#jsonrenderer).
- [SessionAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication).
- [BasicAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication).
- Permission [IsAuthenticated](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated).